# Mudar a imagem conforme a resolução da tela

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou estudando alguma coisa em `jQuery` para o caso.
É possível mudar uma imagem conforme a resolução da tela?

Por exemplo: no próprio navegador, com ele sem minimizar é a imagem grande.
Se minimizar, a função troca para a imagem pequena.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível! Podes fazê-lo utilizando o método [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

> Descrição: O `.width()` obtem a largura atual calculada para o primeiro elemento no conjunto de elementos correspondentes apontados.

Neste caso o elemento correspondeste apontado será a `window`, para obtermos a largura da janela/*[viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)*:

```
$(window).width()
```

Depois iremos calcular se a largura do viewport é ou não maior que um valor que queiramos determinar, por exemplo:

```js
if ($(window).width() > 500) {
   alert('A largura da janela é menor que 500');
} else {
   alert('A largura da janela é maior que 500');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Aqui tens também um [exemplo no jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/hhyk6guj/) para veres este código em acção. Arrasta as bordas da secção de resultados diminuindo ou aumentando o tamanho da janela para veres a imagem a mudar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar uma chamada para a sua função dentro do `$(window).resize(function() { ... });`.
Sugiro usar `document.body.scrollWidth` ao invés de `$(window).width()` pois o primeiro pega a largura de dentro da tela descontando a barra de rolagem, borda do browser, etc.